# How to get updated Model converting in json using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am stuck on one stuff..
I am converting Model into json format like

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

Its getting called on texfield blur event. Issue is Model is not getting updated value of textfield

**Here is my jQuery**

```
$("#pin").blur(function () {
    var url='@Url.Action("validatePin", "PinRegistration")';
    var model=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $.post(url,model, function (res) {
    });
});
```

Comment: Because `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` is razor code - its parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Use `$('form').serialize()` if you want to serialize the values of your form controls (or just build your object manually based on the value of your form controls)

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` runs server-side. Serializing the form data using jQuery (`serialize`) is better when using AJAX POST-ing.

Comment: Will it pass as a ViewModel which i use at controller?

Comment: Assuming you have generated your form controls correctly, then yes.

Comment: Its done..Thanks